# ¿Cómo puedo monitorear una aplicación para saber si está ejecutándose?

Tags: c#

Tengo un programa que cada vez que note algún cambio sobre un tipo de archivo en un directorio, ejecutará una aplicación externa a C#.
El problema radica cuando el archivo cambia varias veces seguidas *por ejemplo 2 veces en un tiempo de 5 segundos* el programa se ejecuta, y si se abre más de una vez se vuelve loco y no funciona.
Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de validar si esa aplicación se está ejecutando desde C# y en caso de que se esté ejecutando, que no la ejecute.

Aquí el código de mi proyecto.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Encodings;
using System.Threading;
using ExcelDataReader;

namespace FinalBiometrico
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {

                FileSystemWatcher monitor = new FileSystemWatcher
                {
                    // Path = @"C:\Users\yersson.hernandes\Desktop",
                    Path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\701Server",
                    // Filter = "*.xls",
                    Filter = "*.msg",
                    IncludeSubdirectories = false

                };
                WaitForChangedResult result =
                monitor.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Changed);
                //Trace.WriteLine("Se ha detectado movimiento con los archivos de excel");
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.UseShellExecute = true;
                info.FileName = "robot.exe";                
                info.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";               
                Process.Start(info);





            }
        }
    }
}
```

Había leído por ahí que hay un método o función del paquete `System.Diagnostic`  para eso, pero la verdad necesito una guía. Muchas gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos aqui un ejemplo que lo tengo vb.net

```
Private Function CheckAppRunning(AppName As String) As Boolean
        Dim isopen As Boolean = False
        Dim PS() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(AppName)
        If PS.Length = 0 Then
            isopen = False
        Else
            isopen = True
        End If
        Return isopen
    End Function

    Private Sub KillAppProcess(Appname)
        Dim PS() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(Appname)
        If PS.Length > 0 Then
            For Each p As Process In PS
                p.Kill()
                p.WaitForExit()

            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

puedes quitar el `p.WaitForExit()` para no esperar a que la aplicación se cierre.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que recurrir a `Process.GetProcessesByName(proceso)` de `System.Diagnostics` que te dará la lista de procesos activos cuyo nombre de ejecutable sea el del parámetro pasado.

Si existe un proceso con el nombre "robot", sal del proceso actual:

```
Process[] miProceso = Process.GetProcessesByName("robot");
if(miProceso.Length > 0)
{
    this.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Sale un error en la línea de `Proccess.Exit(0);`
`CS0117 C# 'Process' does not contain a definition for 'Exit'`

Comment: Quitale el Process y deja solo Exit(0) o this.Exit(0)